# The principle of extreme

Tags: logic

What is the minimum number of colors you can paint all natural numbers so that any two natural numbers that differ in 4 or 8 times, were painted in different colors?

Comment: What do you mean by "differ in 4 or 8 times"? Can you explain it, or perhaps give us some examples of numbers that "differ in 4 or 8 times", and some numbers that don't?

Comment: Plz also post the context of the problem, your own thoughts and the work you did on it. It's likely to be taken negatively on the platform if you don't do that.

Comment: For example, 1, 4, 8 or 8, 2, 1

Comment: @Anatol Please give a precise mathematical definition for "differ in 4 or 8 times". So far, I don't understand what you're trying to say.

Comment: So ... the painting should be done such that there is no whole number $n$ such that $n$ and $4n$ are painted in the same color, or $n$ and $8n$ are painted in the same color.  Right?

Comment: If we will consistently paint the natural numbers in ascending order than there are no more than two restrictions for the color of each number k > 8: it cannot be the same color with either k/4 or k/8. Therefore, for any such k there will be a third color.

Comment: @Anatol You should really add that further explanation and thoughts to your post.  As you can see, people are already downvoting your post because you didn;t do so.

Comment: Consider a combination of numbers (1, 4, and 8) or (8, 2, 1). Any two of them must be painted in different colors, so the colors can not be less than three.

Comment: I hope my last explanation is clear?

Comment: In my understanding $(\color{red}{1}, \color{blue}{4}, \color{blue}{8})$ is a valid coloring of your first example because $4$ and $8$ differ in a factor of $2$ so they can have the same color.

Comment: That's the problem, it all depends on the number from which we start counting. If from 1, then there should be three colors, and if we count down from 8, then for this combination of numbers you are right. There are no additional explanations for this task.

Answer (score 0):

I understand your question like that:

> Find the minimal $n$ such that there exists a coloring function $c:ℕ→ \{c_1,c_2,…,c_n\} $ with $c(i) \ne c(4i)$ and $c(i) \ne c(8i)$ for all $i∈ℕ$.

**Hint**:

First try to find a coloring such that $c(i)\ne c(i+2)$ and $c(i)\ne c(i+3)$. There exists a quite simple coloring with three colors. And you should be able to find a counterexample that two colors do not suffice.

Then think about the prime factorization of $4i$ and $8i$ compared to the one of $i$.